# Move from LDAP user identification to ADFS

Tags: authentication, nfc, adfs, rfid

In a legacy Windows Forms application, users are now identified by an LDAP query. In essence, they scan their badge (barcode) and the application runs an LDAP query to get user attributes.

I know, from a security perspective, this is bad, but usability is more important than security in this case (we're talking about machine operators and they just need to sign-in / sign-off).

Now, we would like to move to a web-based architecture and the simplest thing would be to run the LDAP queries from the back-end to achieve the same.

However, I was wondering if we could switch to a more secure solution using ADFS and RFID/NFC badges, but I can't find any existing implementation. (I'm not looking for 2FA).

So, I'm trying SO, knowing this question can result in opinionated answers: if anyone has experience with a similar use-case, please stand up.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS doesn't do this OOTB.

You could write a [custom](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudpfe/2014/02/01/how-to-create-a-custom-authentication-provider-for-active-directory-federation-services-on-windows-server-2012-r2-part-2/) authentication feature or use the [MFA server](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/bulentozkir/2016/08/18/deploying-your-mfa-server-on-premises-that-is-integrated-with-adfs-server/).

I see you don't want MFA but if you look at the screenshot, it does more than MFA.